# Android: ExpandableListView drawable group indicator being big when i using my own icon

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using this codes to set my own group indicator icon and set it to right side of the list

```
ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.SCHEDULE);

Drawable icon = StationInfo2.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.expander_group);

list.setGroupIndicator(icon);

list.setIndicatorBounds(list.getWidth() - 80, list.getWidth() - 40);
```

Its works to show my own icon but the icon shows in wrong size.

Becouse i am new here i can not post links or image to show how its looks like but i hope someone has a good idea how i can do?

Comment: I have now removed the group indicator and set a ImageView i can control my self on events, works fine.

Comment: How did you set an ImageView instead of a group indicator? I found this post useful http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/configuring-the-icons-of-an-expandablelistview-a-simple-ex-t12075.html

Comment: Did you solve a problem with big indicator size? I have the same one

Answer (score 2):

You should draw it using 9-patch.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html
Put black pixel to the corners. that will help. (contact me if you need more info).
Look at the origingal one you see black dots? make them for your image.
[image]